# MySQL: How to set `HAVING` condition for timestamp this post-query filter?

Tags: mysql, having-clause

It's the first time I try to use the 'HAVING' clause in my SQL: I need to only show the items in a valid period to the customer. I'm very confused by the bellow test result:

```
MariaDB [n4_2]> CREATE TABLE `test_01` (
    ->   `create_time` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ->   `expire_time` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.012 sec)

MariaDB [n4_2]> INSERT INTO `test_01` VALUES (1495000000, 1790000000);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.003 sec)

MariaDB [n4_2]> SELECT
    ->   UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AS "timeStamp",
    ->   `test_01`.`expire_time` AS "expire_time",
    ->   `test_01`.`expire_time` - UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AS "diff"
    -> FROM `test_01`
    -> HAVING "timeStamp" > "expire_time";
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| timeStamp  | expire_time | diff      |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1571664550 |  1790000000 | 218335450 |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [n4_2]> SELECT
    ->   UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AS "timeStamp",
    ->   `test_01`.`expire_time` AS "expire_time",
    ->   `test_01`.`expire_time` - UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AS "diff"
    -> FROM `test_01`
    -> HAVING "timeStamp" < "expire_time";
Empty set (0.000 sec)
```

The question is: why condition `HAVING "timeStamp" < "expire_time"` failed to get the record but condition `HAVING "timeStamp" >= "expire_time"` got the record? Obviously the timestamp of NOW is smaller than the expire_time.

Comment: Having is not meant to be used like this in my opinion. You can use a WHERE clause here.

Comment: @Daniel E. change `HAVING` to `WHERE` gets the same result.

Comment: You are escaping the field names incorrectly. Don't use double quotes or just use `\`field\``. When you use `HAVING "timeStamp" < "expire_time"` you are comparing two strings.

Comment: @LucasMartins OMG what a stupid mistake... Corrected and it worked. Thank you for point this out ;)

Comment: @LucasMartins MySQL has extended the ANSI/ISO standard where aliases can be used which does not make it more easy and mistakes like these can and will happen..  But zipper next time when wierd things like this happen -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ok7npZXqvzdAxezVYc439x/6 .. Notice the internal "SQL" rewite happen notice that `<cache>` is non valid SQL..

Comment: So MySQL is executing , these [queries](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ok7npZXqvzdAxezVYc439x/14)  instead..  So it is best to use the ANSI/ISO standard and use `WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() <  test_01`.`expire_time`  to avoid wierd things to happen..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks that's a good resource;) As for the second comment, `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is simple enough the engine may only evaluate one time, but in general it may evaluate the same expression at different places twice (pure guess) so I still think aliasing is meaningful here.

Comment: *"but in general it may evaluate the same expression at different places twice (pure guess) so I still think aliasing is meaningful here."* Would you rather have SQL that 100% gives correct results on every run or the method that is maybe 0.01% faster but might be 80% of the times correct.... Also the internal caching off the same expression in the MySQL optimizer is much better then you expect..